# Preventing exceptions when an Access SQL query returns a blank record

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

The following function will throw an exception if the resulting field it found from the Access SQL query is empty.

If the query turns up empty, I just want retvalue to = nothing, but I get an error saying that I can't assign a null value to a string. So I put it in a catch, but the catch lags the application as this function is used quite often, and the query results are frequently empty.

An example situation would be:

checkRecord("Notes", "Table1", "First Name", "Steve")

The function returns the notes field for the record with a first name value of "Steve" in Table 1. If Steve's notes are empty (they often are), the function will throw an exception about converting a string to null.

How can I have it declare retvalue = nothing if the returned database record is empty, without having to do a catch?

```
 Public Shared Function CheckRecord(Table As String, refcol As String, refcolvalue As String, targetcol As String)


        Dim retvalue As String

        Using cn As New OleDbConnection(mystr)
            cn.Open()
            Dim custCMDcr As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT [" & targetcol & "] FROM [" & Table & "] WHERE [" & refcol & "] =" & refcolvalue)


            custCMDcr.Connection = cn



            Try
            retvalue = CType(custCMDcr.ExecuteScalar(), String).ToString

            Catch fail As Exception
                retvalue = Nothing
            End Try



            Return retvalue



        End Using





    End Function
```

Comment: test the return using IsDbNull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing the result using isDBNULL worked, thank you!

```
If IsDBNull(custCMDcr.ExecuteScalar()) Then
    retvalue = Nothing
else 
    (rest of code)
end if
```